# Firebase Filteringdata with php

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already tested this [Firebase Filtering data with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883615/firebase-filtering-data-with-php) but im getting this error and i dont have any clue how to debug this

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
>   error: `GET
>   https://table.firebaseio.com/tbl_admin?orderBy=%22username%22&equalTo=%22admin%22&limitToFirst=1`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error" : "Index not
>   defined, add \".indexOn\": \"username\", for path \"/tbl_admin\", to
>   the rules" } in
>   D:\Xampp\htdocs\firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Xampp\htdocs\firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(66):
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1
>   D:\Xampp\htdocs\firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(203):
>   GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
>
> ## 2 D:\Xampp\htdocs\firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(156):
>
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1,
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3
>   D:\Xampp\htdocs\firebase\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(47):
>   GuzzleHttp\Prom in
>   D:\Xampp\htdocs\firebase\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\QueryException.php
>   on line 28

how will i filter this on firebase  as i have queried it on mysql like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE username = 'admin'
```

[image: A table structure on firebase]

Comment: Inlined image so users don't have to navigate away from StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message, you'll find that it says:

> Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "username", for path "/tbl_admin", to the rules

You can add those rules by navigating to the Database Rules section in the Firebase Web Console of your project (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/_/rules should™ bring you there) and adding the index so that your rules look something like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false,
        "tbl_admin": {
          ".indexOn": ["username"]
        }
    }
}
```

The important part is the `tbl_admin` field, don't just copy and paste the snippet if you already have other settings in your rules ^^.

[image]